# Некорректный вывод данных в файл

Tags: c++, файлы

Я беру данные из одного файла и записываю в другой:

```
 void OutputFile(array* arr, int &n) {
            ofstream fout("test.txt"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                fout << arr[i].Name << endl;
                fout << arr[i].Cost << endl;
                fout << arr[i].Min << endl;
                fout << arr[i].Max << endl;
            }
            fout.close(); 
        }
    void InputFile(array* arr,int &n,bool &flag) {
        char string[20];
        cout << "Input the name of the file:" << endl;
        cin >> string;
        strcat(string, ".txt");
        char *str = new char[1024];
        int i = 0;
        ifstream fin(string);
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            fin.getline(str, 1024, '\n');
            i++;
        }
        delete str;
        fin.close();
        n = i/4;
        arr = new array[n];
        ifstream fin1(string, ios::binary);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            fin1 >> arr[i].Name;
            fin1 >> arr[i].Cost;
            fin1 >> arr[i].Min;
            fin1 >> arr[i].Max;
        }
        fin1.close();
}


void main() {
    int n = 0;
    array* arr= new array[n];
    bool flag = false;
    InputFile(arr,n, flag);
    Output(arr, n);
}
```

Но вместо данных, в файле отображаются иероглифы. Как это исправить?
array - структура данных

```
struct array {
    char Name[20];
    double Cost;
    short int Min, Max;
};
```

В файле содержится следующий текст:

```
one
400
2
5
two
375
2
5
three
399
2
5
```

А выводится в файл следующее:

```
ээээЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭсП™NЋ­
8.45831e-305
27592
29261

9.42845e-310
-12303
20121
ЂІН
-7.84591e+298
-12851
-12851
```

Windows 10,x64, VS 2015 Pro

Comment: А как вы заполняете массив?

Comment: @Sublihim либо руками все ввожу либо из файла беру, причем когда ввожу руками, все заполняется корректно

Comment: может с кодировкой исходного файла что-то?

Comment: @Sublihim когда беру данные из файла(в файле все корректно введено), то на консоль выводится все также как и в файле, то бишь корректно
Я пытался изменить кодировку,но ничего не поменялось

Comment: Вы можете тут (в тексте вопроса) привести минимальный компилируемый (и потом запускаемый) код + исходные данные, который воспроизводит вашу проблему? (и ОС сразу укажите)

Comment: Почему в вопросе не приведено объявление типа `array`? И почему об этом надо напоминать? Судя по именам полей, некоторые из них - числовые? Если это так, то хотя бы для этих полей никаких "иероглифов" в файле быть не может. В общем, хватить выдумывать - приводите вменяемое описание проблемы. Пока что - "бэ, мэ, макрамэ".

Comment: a `.Name` - а это случайно не `char*` ?

Comment: @KoVadim да, это строка

Comment: @avp все добавил

Comment: делайте его `std::string`. Вы же работаете в с++!

Comment: @KoVadim но числовые значения же тоже неправильно отображаются

Comment: В `OutputFile()` печатаете мусор, а не то, что вводите (что ввели теряется внутри `InputFile()`) (но не очтаивайтесь, я думаю, сейчас вам насыпят советов, как правильно делать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в функции `InputFile` выделяется свой собственный массив для чтения данных. Вот в него вы и читаете данные. В функцию `main` вы этот массив никак не возвращаете - он просто тихо "забывается" (становится утечкой памяти по выходу из `InputFile`).

Массив, который вы создали ранее в `main` (размера 0?) ничего об этом не знает и никакого отношения к читаемому из файла массиву не имеет. Он никак ни для чего не используется и никакие данные в него не попадают.

Потом вы пытаетесь посылать на выход в функцию `OutputFile` именно массив нулевого размера из `main`. Неудивительно, что на выход попадает какой-то бессмысленный мусор. (Не говоря уже о том, что массив имеет нулевой размер, а вы в него пытаетесь доступаться.)

По тому, как вы щедро используете ссылки в объявлениях параметров вашей функции `InputFile` понятно, что вы уже сталкивались с темой "передачи параметров по значению", "передачи параметров по ссылке" и т.п. (Даже в `OutputFile` параметр `n` передается по ссылке!). А что же вы ваш указатель оставили без такого внимания? Что-то в этом роде вам и надо сделать с вашим указателем тоже, чтобы он *возвращался* из функции `InputFile` обратно в `main`, а не превращался в утечку памяти. А выделять в `main` массив размера 0 никакого смысла нет.

И `int main()`, а не `void main()`. И цикл с предусловием "пока не EOF" - практически всегда ошибка в С и С++. И освобождение памяти после `new[]` делается через `delete[]`, а не через `delete`. И с чего это вдруг поток для выполнения форматированного чтения у вас открывается как binary?

Comment: большое спасибо,подправил кое-что, не подскажете как подсчитать кол-во строк в файле другим способом?

Comment: @Draktharon: В С++ - см. вот http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072840/187690